# Sup norm of vector-valued function

Tags: functional-analysis

If $\vec{u}$ is a real-valued vector-valued function, say $\vec{u}=(u_1,u_2,u_3)$, is the following correct?
$$\|\vec{u}\|_{\infty}=\sum_{i=1}^3\sup|u_i|.$$

Comment: It is a function of what variable?  You want the infinity norm with respect to that variable?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that $u_1$, $u_2$, and $u_3$ are continuous function than the supremum norm can be written as 
$$\|\vec{u}\|_{\infty}=\sup\{\sup |u_i|\text{ with }i=1,2,3\}.$$
If the functions $u_i$ are continuous and defined on a compact set, then the $\sup$ can be replaced by $\max$. 
For the more general cases, I would refer to the Wikipedia page https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L-infinity 
$$\|\vec{u}\|_{\infty}=\inf\{C \text{ such that } |u_i(x)|<C\text{ for almost every }x,\text{ with }i=1,2,3\}.$$

Answer (score 0):

$$\|\vec{u}\|_{\infty}=\max_{1\leq i\leq3} |u_i|$$